# Asp.net mvc5 footer displaying at the top of page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having some trouble trying to display details on my asp.net web page. I am trying to display details on the left hand side of the page and also be able to create an item on the right hand side of the page. I am using a partial view for the create part and using the following html

### ViewLift

```
<div>
    <h4>Lift</h4>
    <hr />
        <dl class="dl-horizontal" id="details">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartPoint)
            </dt>

            <dd id="startPoint">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StartPoint)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndPoint)
            </dt>

            <dd id="endPoint">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EndPoint)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LiftDate)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LiftDate)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OutboundStartTime)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OutboundStartTime)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OutboundEndTime)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OutboundEndTime)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InboundStartTime)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.InboundStartTime)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InboundEndTime)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.InboundEndTime)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserEmailAddress)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserEmailAddress)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserId)
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <div id="LiftRequest-dialog" title="Request Lift">
        @Html.Action("RequestLiftPartialView", new Carpool.Models.RequestLift())
    </div>
```

Then the following css

```
<style>
        #details {
            float:left;
        }

        #LiftRequest-dialog{
            float:right;
        }
    </style>
```

However although they display to the left and right for some reason the footer of my application is displaying just above them. The footer is the default one which is in the _Layout page. Is the way I am trying to lay them out the wrong way or can someone tell me why the footer moved without me changing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/). Create a CSS style definition like:

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Then, then apply this class to the parent of your floated elements:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div id="FloatedElement1"></div>
    <div id="FloatedElement2"></div>
</div>

<div id="Footer"></div>
```

Essentially, what's happening here is that floated elements are removed from the normal document flow. The footer, meanwhile, is part of the flow and, since there's apparently nothing else it's succeeding, goes all the way to the top. It then tries to "wrap" around the floated elements, but since there's not enough horizontal space for all that, those floats fall off the line, ending up below it. The clearfix causes the "wrapper" around the float elements to be itself part of the document flow, which serves to push elements after it down the page, namely, your footer.

Comment: That worked perfect thanks @Chris Pratt. While I have you can ask is there a way of setting the divs so they they display right beside each other? When I float them left and right my labels are sometimes too long and they are so far to the right it displays them in 2-3 lines.

Comment: The width of floats is determined based on the width of their contents. A table's width, too, is determine based on the width of its contents. So, essentially, you have nothing providing any sort of width for the area other than the text itself. You should set a defined width on your float and set your table width to be 100%, so it fills the defined width of the float. You might also want to look into using flexbox, which makes all of this orders of magnitude easier. The only issue is that it's IE 10+ (and every other browser on earth) only.

Comment: Whoops. I read "labels" as "tables", but the above still mostly applies. You need a defined width on your float or something inside the float with a defined width to force it out.

Comment: FWIW, it's very helpful when working with floats to give them a background color, so you can actually see the area the float is occupying. It helps to make issues like this obvious, as you can then visibly discern that it's not occupying the width you expected it to.